# Ошибка при добавлении символа

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме есть текстбокс, при добавлении в него символа, должен был добавляться спец. символ, в моём случае "|", но у меня появляется ошибка:

> Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
>   Необработанное исключение типа "System.StackOverflowException" в System.Windows.Forms.dll

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "|";
}
```

Comment: Все дело в событии `TextChanged`, у вас происходит зацикливание: в событии изменения текста, вы изменяете текст, что в свою очередь вызывает снова это же событие...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!textBox1.Text.EndsWith("|"))
            textBox1.Text += "|";
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

решено, временно отключил событие

```
 public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "|";
        textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
    }
```

Comment: Кривенькое решение, как левой рукой чесать правое ухо.

Comment: мне всё это пришлось добавить ещё к 19 текстбоксам